# Same Length Error (errorbar plotting matlab)

Tags: matlab, plot, errorbar

New user here! Currently trying to plot error bars composed of the confidence interval, and the data set consists of coordinates of a previously calculated contour (cmatrix). I'm getting this error:

```
x, y, and errorbars must all be the same length.
```

`midpointPositionMean` and `midpointPositionConf95` are both 4x3 matrices composed of 1x8 vectors. `midpointPosition` is a 3x4 matrix. `StatsonCells` calculates mean and confidence interval of 95%. What do I have to change?

```
[midpointPositionMean,midpointPositionConf95]=StatsOnCells(midpointPosition');

errorbar([0.85,1.15,1.45],...
  cell2mat(midpointPositionMean),...
  cell2mat(midpointPositionConf95),...
  'bx');
hold on;
plot(repmat(0.85,size(midpointPosition(1,:))),...
  midpointPosition(1,:),'ob','MarkerFaceColor','b')

plot(repmat(1.15,size(midpointPosition(2,:))),...
  midpointPosition(2,:),'ob','MarkerFaceColor','b')

plot(repmat(1.45,size(midpointPosition(3,:))),...
  midpointPosition(3,:),'ob','MarkerFaceColor','b')
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Your `X` has only 3 values `[0.85,1.15,1.45]`, while `Y` and `E` are 24x4.